# How to assign the result of a for loop to a variable in Python

Tags: python

My program generates a random string with a random amount of letters from 10 to 20.

```
def program():
    import random
    import sys
    x=['q','w','e','r']
    y=random.randint(10,20)
    for t in range (0,y):
       w=random.randint(0,3)
       e=x[w]
       sys.stdout.write(e)
```

The program will print a random string like 'wwwweewwqqrrrrwwqqeeqqww'. How would I store this string as a variable?

Comment: Instead of writing, store the result into a string or array.

Comment: As a side note: `e = random.choice(x)` is much more readable than `w = random.randint(0, 3); e = x[w]`.

Comment: In fact, you could replace this entire function with `return ''.join(random.choices('qwer', k=random.randint(10, 20)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it in a variable instead of writing:

```
e=''

for t in range (0,y):
    w=random.randint(0,3)
    e += x[w]
```

`e` is an empty variable and each time you add the value `x[w]` to it.

I would also recommend using `print()` over  `sys.stdout.write(e)` since you do not need additional imports -such as `sys`, `print()` is inbuilt.

In this case can I suggest the use of  a tuple for `x=['q','w','e','r']` since they are faster.  So: `x=('q','w','e','r'1)`

but if you are going to need to modify this later then this is not an option available to you (since they are immutable).

Answer (score 3):

You could replace your loop with a list comprehension, and use `join()`:

```
e = ''.join([random.choice(x) for _ in range(0, y)])
```

Output:

```
qwewwwereeeqeqww
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I feel like it would be hard to understand for someone who's new to python (like the OP seems to be).

Answer (score 2):

```
def program():
   import random
   x=['q','w','e','r']
   y=random.randint(10,20)
   mystr=''
   for t in range (0,y):
      w=random.randint(0,3)
      e=x[w]
      mystr=mystr+e
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation with your code so that the OP and future visitors know what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like you can have`program()` returns the output variable like so:

```
def program():
    import random
    import sys
    x=['q','w','e','r']
    y=random.randint(10,20)
    output = ''
    for t in range (0,y):
        w=random.randint(0,3)
        e=x[w]
        output+=e
    # The print is stored in 'output'

    # Return the output
    return output
result = program()
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to create a new string variable and just use the `+=` operator to concatenate each character onto a new string. Your code could be

```
 def program():
   import random
   import sys
   x=['q','w','e','r']
   y=random.randint(10,20)
   z = '';
   for t in range (0,y):
      w=random.randint(0,3)
      e=x[w]
      z += e;
```

This code just adds each character to a string variable `z` in your for loop, and that string value should be stored in `z`.

Answer (score 1):

something like (haven't tested the program, should work... famous last words).

```
# imports at start of file, not in def
import random
import sys

# I would never call a def 'program', kind of generic name, avoid
def my_program():  # camel case, PEP-8
    x=['q','w','e','r']
    z=''  # initialize result as an empty string
    for _ in range (0, random.randint(10,20)):
       z+=x[random.randint(0,3)]  # add a letter to string z
    return z
```

"_" is often used for a throw away variable, see [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)
In this case the _ is used nowhere.